# Receiving data automatically in wifi(ESP8266) Even though connected my mobile with ESP8266

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

Hello friends,

I'm new to arduino.  So please help me to solve this issue.

I'm doing android mobile (IR less) control arduino UNO and WIFI (ESP8266) based TV control.  I connected my mobile phone wifi with ESP8266 and I'm sending data to ESP8266 to control TV.

But it receives random values and did not receive values whatever I'm sending through my mobile phone wifi (But both wifi has in connection).   But before I did controlled. Now I couldn't control I don't know why.  And also how to stop this random value reception.

I'm attaching my code here

```
#include<IRremote.h>
IRsend ir;

char serialA;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
   // Serial communication 
  Serial.begin(115200); 

   // Wifi commands

  Serial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.end();
}

void loop()
{
  delay(800);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (Serial.available() > 0 )
  {
    serialA = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(serialA);
    IRREMOTE();
  }
}
void IRREMOTE()
{
    switch (serialA)
  {

    case 'A':         //Power
      ir.sendNEC(0x2FD48B7, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'B':         // AV/TV
      ir.sendNEC(0x2FD28D7, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'C':         // Mute
      ir.sendNEC(0x2FD08F7, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'D':      // CH+
      ir.sendNEC(0x2FDD827, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;


    case 'E':    // CH-

      ir.sendNEC(0x2FDF807, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'F':    // Vol+

      ir.sendNEC(0x2FD58A7, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'G':    // Vol-

      ir.sendNEC(0x2FD7887, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'H':
      //  Menu
      ir.sendNEC(0x2FD30CF, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'I':
      //  Alt
      ir.sendNEC(0x2FD708F, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;

    case 'J':
      // Scan
      ir.sendNEC(0x2FDDA25, 32);
      delay(500);
      break;
  }
}

Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but you sent

> Serial.println("AT");

instead of `Serial.println("AT\r\n");`.

To initialize the ESP8266 you normally start with a reset so maybe you should add 
`Serial.println("AT+RST\r\n");
delay(500);`

above your AT command.

Furthermore, you start your communication in the setup() and you repeat it in the loop(). The line in the loop() shouldn't be necessary!

Would be nice to see the random values which you received! Maybe I can find the problem (could be something wrong depending on the ASCII table)

Answer (score 0):

try adding Serial.Flush() after every Serial data sent to the ESP